# MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where no ='count'

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I have this problem:

> MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where  no ='count'' at line 1

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick

    MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
    MysqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=penjara"
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader

    MysqlConn.Open()

    Dim query As String
    Dim spath As String
    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim mysound As Media.SoundPlayer
    Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
    Dim rdr As MySqlDataReader


    query = "Select * from penjara.info"
    Command = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
    Reader = Command.ExecuteReader



    While Reader.Read
        Reader.Close()
        count = count + 1
        query = "Select penjara.info where  no ='count'"
        cmd = New MySqlCommand(query, MysqlConn)
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    End While
End Sub
```

How can I solve this error?

Comment: In the future, please only include the relevant code. I've edited your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
query = "Select * from penjara.info where  no = '" & count & "'"
```

This will pass in the value of variable `count`. However, note that this is an unsafe approach since concatenating to form queries makes your app vulnerable to SQL Injection. Instead you should use parameterised queries.

```
Dim connStr As String = "server=localhost;userid=root;password=;database=penjara"
Using MySqlConn As New MySqlConnection(connStr)
Using cmd As New MySqlCommand()
    With cmd
        .Connection = MySqlConn
        .CommandText = "Select * from penjara.info where  no = @count"
        .CommandType = CommandType.Text
        .Parameters.AddWithValue("@count", count)
    End With
    Try
        MySql.Open()
        rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    Catch ex As Exception
        <handle exception>
    End Try
End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Try my updated code. I assume you want to do `select * from`?